# Why doesn't pulling in your arms on a rotating stool violate conservation of energy?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

From what I understand, pulling in one's arms on a rotating stool would decrease the radius, thus decreasing the moment of inertia. If we decrease the radius enough to halve the moment of inertia, we would **double** rotational kinetic energy, since the angular velocity (which is squared) would double.

If this is so, where is this energy coming from? It doesn't seem as if an external force is doing work on the system. Is there some form of potential energy here being converted to kinetic energy?

Comment: You should try it yourself. Then it will become evident.

Comment: This is a classic example of my maxim: invoking the human body will _never_ elucidate a physical principle.

Comment: Is it easy to pull you arms in?